# UIButton CGPoint

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have 10 UIButtons (l1,l2,l3...l10) also BOOL c1, c2, c3,...c10.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    c1 = true;
    ////c2,3,..c10 = false

}
```

Now, If I press a button, i have this code:

```
- (IBAction)tapButton:(id)sender {

    ///// if user press first Button
    if([sender tag] == 1)
    {

        if(c1 = true){
        /// move l1 button to a1 position & set c1 false and open c2.
        l1.center = a1.center
        c1 = false;
        c2 = true;
    }

    else if (c1 = false)
    {

        /// return l1 button to "o" position (original position)
        l1.center = o1.center;
    }

}
```

this code works for this button, if i try to repeat for "SENDER TAG 2, 3... 10" doesn't work well. I just try to use exactly the same trick like word games uses.

If you press a letter, it should go to first box/position, if you press another one, it should go to second box/position, if you press one letter from box/position, it should come back to original position..

Please help me, how to make it to work. Maybe using switch, or something like that.

Thanks

Comment: Fix the title please, it's not very meaningful.

Comment: On btn, what tag you are set please show.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I notice, besides the fact that for convention we use YES instead of true, is that you aren't evaluating the value of c1, but assigning it (the comparison will always result true). The correct piece of code is:

```
if(c1 == YES) {...}
```

Or just:

```
if(c1) {...}
```

Let me know if it works, there may be other problems.